# Variable Transformations in Confirmatory Factor Analysis

Tags: python, categorical-data, factor-analysis, ordinal-data, confirmatory-factor

I plan to implement CFA on a dataset, with 6 independent variables and 1 dependent variable. My independent variables are demographics that include 1 continuous variable (e.g., age 18 years old, 60 years old), 2 ordinal variables (e.g., read for 2-3 hours/day, 3-7 hours/day), 3 categorical variables (e.g., male-female, left-handed vs. right-handed). The dependent variable is an ordinal variable (i.e., 1-4 Likert scale self-evaluation score). My question is:

I only have one dependent variable. I guess I will use one common factor CFA. How do I include the rank in the factor definition? I'm using factor_analyzer python package https://pypi.org/project/factor-analyzer/ . I wonder what should I put in the 'model_direct' part to indicate rank information.

Comment: Variables in which another variable is binned are ordinal, not interval (scale).

Comment: Why transform anything at all? Four of your predictor variables are fine as they are and there is no point to transforming age unless theory or prior analysis indicates a nonlinear relationship.

Comment: Although the terminology of dependent and independent variables lingers on, there are many more evocative terms such as response or outcome for dependent variable. Also, people new to this can get confused on which is which (typo in first sentence of your point 2).

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. I just revised my typo. I see that people recommend standardizing variables before factor analyses. By saying transform, I am referring to the final input variable format. Are you saying that I can just put category names in the column for the categorical variable as the input? How to indicate rank info then?

Comment: I can't see that your data lend themselves to CFA at all.

Comment: Why another method would you use to analyze the structure of the dataset then? I've already used regression and I'm searching for a method in addition to regression. I've seen papers talking about using CFA for ordinal data. Why do you think it's not a good fit here?

Comment: Is there any reason why you do  not want to use ordinal logistic regression?

Comment: The reason is I've already done ordinal logistic regression in my very first step. And I want to dig deeper and see I can find more latent variables from the data via factor analysis.