# How to deal with categorical variables in factor analysis

Tags: categorical-data, factor-analysis

I have a dataset. Most of my independent variables are ordinal variables (e.g., age), but one is a categorical variable (i.e., environment: city, rural, suburb). I'm wondering how I should deal with the categorical variable here?

Thanks,
Lily

Comment: Do you mean exploratory or confirmatory factor analysis? In the latter, you can adjust for the categorical variable with more ease or you could do group-wise CFA. What exactly is your research question?

Comment: My research question is to look at how some demographic factors could explain a certain type of cognitive ability (the dependent variable is a 4-point Likert scaled ordinal variable). I want to try both exploratory and confirmatory analysis. Could you please please specify how to deal with categorical independent variables in each type of analysis? In CFA, what do you mean by adjusting variables with more ease and what is group-wise CFA?

Comment: I am not sure why you need factor analysis then. Why not go for multiple multinomial regression?

Comment: I've already done regression as a first step. I want to look deeper into data structure by using factor analysis. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variable Transformations in Confirmatory Factor Analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/530585/variable-transformations-in-confirmatory-factor-analysis)

Comment: It is rather uncommon to fo FA on demographic variables. Moreover, including categorical variables is not easy because EFA is based on the correlation matrix of the included variables and the most common types of correlation assume at least ordinal - but in many cases continuous - variables. I wonder if it is worth the effort and what the additional value of such analysis would be.

Comment: Oops. I'm actually the one who raised that question in the other thread. I don't think there is a good answer to this.